# Magmi Logs and how to get better records

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magmi, log

I'm almost done with a Import tool that can use Magmi API to update the products. What I'm looking for is a way to log the failed updates so if I need to build a 're'queue system, I will. This cron will run every 10 minutes. It's just a lot of data and I need to make sure that everything is always in Sync.

The datapump is going from MySQL to Magento. I'm open for other suggestion to on importing/updating product from another MySQL table. However, Magmi seems to be the closest for us right now.